# Resizing the image with padding using convert on ubuntu

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, image-resizing

I am using the convert command for resizing the image

There are two versions

Following is the first one, the resultant image maintains the aspect ratio but the image does not necessarily be of size `nxn`

```
 convert temp.jpg -resize nxn temp.jpg
```

The second version

```
 convert temp.jpg -resize nxn! temp.jpg
```

It does not preserve the aspect ratio.

What I want is to preserve the aspect ratio, and fill the rest of the image with a desired RGB value to acheive the size `nxn`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try with ffmpeg :https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg

Comment: +1 to @Rupesh, pro tip, with many image manipulations, ffmpeg does the job faster than ImageMagick (especially when working with large image files)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to use `-extent` to set the size of the canvas directly after you have resized, and the newly created area will be filled with whatever you set the `-background` to.

So, if you want the padding to be magenta, do this:

```
convert image.png -resize 100x100 -background "rgb(255,0,255)" -extent 100x100 out.png
```

If you want your image to appear *"in the middle"* of the output image, with the padding evenly spaced around the sides, add in `-gravity center` like this:

```
convert image.png -resize 100x100 -gravity center -background "rgb(255,0,255)" -extent 100x100 out.png
```

So, if we start with a wide blue image, that is 300x100 and has no chance of fitting properly in a square, as follows:

[image]

and we resize it with this:

```
convert image.png -resize 100x100 -gravity center -background "rgb(255,0,255)" -extent 100x100 out.png
```

we will get this

[image]

Comment: Its a perfect answer and worked for my problem, sorry for being late as I was away, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I used this answer to make a square logo work for GSuite: `convert -resize 132x132 -gravity center -background "rgb(255,255,255)" -extent 320x132 in.png out.png` .  The logo was resized to the smaller 132px square and ended up in the middle of the 320x132px white rectangle.  Thanks @mark !